# To restrict the empty fields while dynamically adding the form fields

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6

**Scenario:**

I am dynamically adding some **fields value(i,e Employee Type/ID/Name)** like this:

[image]

Even the fields are empty,still it is displaying empty values as shown below:

[image]

**Expected Result:**

- I want to print/display field values only when **dropdown**(i,e Employee Type is selected) and **input field**(i,e Employee ID is filled).
- Need not to display empty values.

Stackblitz **[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-bdxu36?file=app/demo/demo.component.html)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first check if is empty then do not push into array otherwise push into the Array. Like this

```
addFieldValue() {
if (this.newAttribute.employee && this.newAttribute.id) {
  if (this.fieldArray.indexOf(this.newAttribute) === -1) {
    this.fieldArray.push(this.newAttribute)
  }
}
this.newAttribute = {};
console.log(this.fieldArray); }
```

Comment: @Empty_Soul once added then you can empty `this.newAttribute = {}`. In my answer check it.

Comment: Now its working, but when i click on `pen-icon(i,e edit)` , I will go back to the fields to `edit` , While editing if left 'input field empty(i,e Employee ID)` still it will display the empty value.

Comment: @Empty_Soul now you can same validate empty condition for edit.

Comment: Ya i got it, I should use same validation for `edit`, I tried .But i am unable to do it.Can you do it for `edit`? If possible.

Comment: @Empty_Soul sorry i can't.